# Where in the Standard does it say that the declaration `auto f()() ->int;` is not allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I know I'm being pedantic here, but I'm just trying to understand the C++ grammar production.

I will start with a *simple-declaration*.

*simple-declaration*:
    *decl-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>   *init-declarator-list*<sub>*opt*</sub>

*decl-specifier-seq*:
    *decl-specifier*

*decl-specifier*:
    *type-specifier*

*type-specifier*:
    *trailing-type-specifier*

*trailing-type-specifier*:
    *simple-type-specifier*

*simple-type-specifier*:
        char
        int
        ...
        auto

---

Now, I'll look into the definition of a *init-declarator-list*.

*init-declarator-list*:
    *init-declarator*

*init-declarator*:
    *declarator*

*declarator*:
    *noptr-declarator*   *parameters and qualifiers*   *trailing return type*    **(*2)**

*noptr-declarator*:
    *declarator-id*   *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
    *noptr-declarator*   *parameters and qualifiers*    **(*1)**

*parameters and qualifiers*:
    (*parameter-declaration-clause*)   *cv-qualifiers*<sub>*opt*</sub>   ... (all optionals)

*trailing-return-type*:
    **-**>   *trailing-type-specifier-seq*

*trailing-type-specifier-seq*:
    *trailing-type-specifier*                See the definition of a *traling-type-specifier* above.

---

Replacing *noptr-declarator* by a *declarator-id* in **(*1)**, using the previous definition of *noptr-declaration*, we arrive at the following definition of *nonptr-declarator*:

*noptr-declaration*:
    *declarator-id*   *parameters and qualifiers*

Now replacing *noptr-declarator*, *parameters and qualifiers* and *trailing-return-type* in **(*2)** by each definition given above, we obtain the following for *declarator*:

*declarator*:
    *declarator-id*   (*parameter-declaration-clause*)   (*parameter-declaration-clause*)   **-**>
                                    *simple-type-specifier*

---

With this last result we could say that the grammar allows the following declaration of a function `f`:

```
auto f()() -> int;
```

which of course is not valid. But I couldn't find anything in the Standard saying, directly or indirectly, that this construction is ill-formed.

The error messages from `GCC` (`f` declared as function returning a function) and `clang` (`auto` return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++1y extensions) didn't help in this regard either.

Comment: It is not allowed because there is no grammar in the Standard which describes this syntax. It is like saying `int f(){} * 100` is not allowed but I don't find anything in Standard that disallows it.

Comment: You are masking the real error here, which is trying to define a function returning a function. `int f()()` is just as invalid.

Comment: How to you arrive at `auto f()() -> int; ` ? You say "_with this last result we could...."_

Comment: @POW In the simple-declaration, make simple-type-specifier = `auto`. Then make declarator-id = `f`, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, the gcc error message is quite helpful: The grammar does in fact allow `auto f()() -> int`, but this syntactically correct declaration is semantically invalid. It would describe a function returning a function returning `int`. See the answer of ecatmur for the standard quote disallowing that.

To understand the parse, work like this. `f` is what you want to declare. Parse to the right, you'll find an empty argument list, so `f()` is a valid expression, and the type of that expression gets declared. Parse again to the right, you'll find an argument list *again*, so the return type of `f` is a function taking zero arguments. Parse again to the right, and you will hit the end (the `->` arrow), so parse to the left to find the result type, which is auto, and gets replaced by the type past the arrow.

Comment: [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cb85f7c7eab2d6c) of the function returning a pointer to a function of type `auto()->int`.  All I added was some `()` around a sub-expression, and a `*` to indicate something is a pointer.  `auto (*f())() -> int`.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you described in your second paragraph above exactly what I was missing (see my comment to ecatmur). Great answer (+1).

Answer (score 11):

**[dcl.fct]**/8:

> [...] Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things. [...]

Comment: @ecatmur This may explain the error emitted by `GCC`, but I don't understand how does this relate to the declaration `auto f()() -> int;`

Comment: @Ayrosa assume `auto f()()->int` is valid.  Then it means the same as `int f()()`.  What is `int f()()`?  A function `f()` returning  a function `int _()`, or `auto _()->int`.  Expand the parse tree, and label each component.

Comment: @Yakk So essentially you're saying that we could rewrite it as `int (f())();` which is... a function returning a function? And if we add a `&` or `*` right before the `f()` we get a pointer or reference, respectively?

Comment: @Columbo yes, I think so.  And at least clang agrees -- `auto (*f())()->int` compiles and is the same type of function as `int (*f())()`.  I haven't had the fun of actually expanding the parse tree, however, so could easily be wrong.